# How to print out only return value of a method?

Tags: java

I've got a homework that I should write a couple of methods(e.g. a method that prompts customer for the car type and returns a valid car type) and then my program should display the car type, number of days car rented for,extras etc. This is first method that teacher wanted me to write ,

```
public static String promptForCarType(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char type;
        System.out.println("(E) Economy  - 50 TL");
        System.out.println("(M) Midsize  - 70 TL");
        System.out.println("(F) Fullsize - 100 TL");
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter the car type (E/M/F) : ");
            type = input.next().charAt(0);
            type = Character.toUpperCase(type);
        } while (type != 'E' && type != 'M' && type != 'F' ); //I tried to define condition with "||" operator,didn't work.


        switch(type) {
            case 'E' : ;return "Economy";             
            case 'M' : return "Midsize";
            case 'F' : return "Fullsize";
            default : return " ";

        }


    }
```

How can I print out only return value of this method ? Should I add System.out.println("Car type is ...) part in promptForCarType()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code control returns to the invoking function when it encounters the keyword **return**. So you can only operate in the current method till the program reaches the keyword return. So, if you need to print something, print it before the return. In your case, you need to print the value in your switch-case construct , for each case before the return statement.

```
 switch(type) {
        case 'E' : System.out.println("Economy");
                   return "Economy";             
       // similarly for each switch case.
    }
```

Or, the better way would be to assign the car type to a variable of type String and then print the value. and write a common return statement for the entire method(for all cases).

```
   String carType;
   switch(type) {
        case 'E' : carType ="Economy";
       // similarly for each switch case.
    }
    System.out.println(carType);
    return carType;
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. So I can't print a return value seperately, without calling the all method right?. I should print it in promptForCarType() I guess..

Comment: You will only enter the method if you call it. So you can either print it inside the method or inside the method that calls promptForCarType() like A4L showed. Either way its correct and does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Call your method from your main method
2. Assign the retrurned value to a variable
3. print that variable

   ```
   String carType = promptForCarType(); //1 + 2
   System.out.println(carType); //3
   ```

Or simply

```
System.out.println(promptForCarType());
```

Comment: When I tried to do this : System.out.println("Car Type is " + promptForCarType()) it displays the possible car types and asks user to choose one again..

Comment: @TronicZomB thanks for the edit, was struggling how to get code-tag inside of list-tag (need to add more spaces).

Comment: @v_7 This is what you want to do! you **prompt** the user for car type input! How do you want the user to know what he needs to input?

Comment: Okay but my question is , Can I print out the return value seperately after I called the method without calling it again?

Comment: @v_7 Yes, use the first variant I've shown, i.e assign the returned value to a local or member variable - depending on when you need it - and print later without having to call the method again!

Comment: You dont have to call it again. You have called it once and it returned you a value. You are just printing the value it returned. So you can print it inside promptForCarType() (before it returns the value to the calling method) or you can print it in the calling method(after it has returned the value).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the instance of the car type you would simply go to your main method and print the called instance of your car accessing the method promptForCar. Ex: System.out.println(object.method);

Answer (score 0):

```
String carType = promptForCarType();
System.out.println("Car type is: " + carType);
```

should work. the return value of promptForCar() is stored in the string carType, and then the print statement uses the string variable to print the return value.
`

Answer (score 0):

You could just return from an infinite loop (and simplify your code) like so -

```
public static String promptForCarType() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char type;
    for (;;) {
        System.out.println("(E) Economy  - 50 TL");
        System.out.println("(M) Midsize  - 70 TL");
        System.out.println("(F) Fullsize - 100 TL");
        System.out.println("Enter the car type (E/M/F) : ");
        type = input.next().charAt(0);
        type = Character.toUpperCase(type);
        switch (type) {
        case 'E':
            return "Economy";
        case 'M':
            return "Midsize";
        case 'F':
            return "Fullsize";
        }
    }
}
```