# How to print a return value from a Method

Tags: java, methods

I am working on a random number method to pick a random element from an array.  However, I don't know how to print the return value from the `getRandom()` method. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CardDeck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Here is your random card.");

        int array[] = new int[13];  

        array[0] = 2;
        array[1] = 3;
        array[2] = 4;
        array[3] = 5;
        array[4] = 6;
        array[5] = 7;
        array[6] = 8;
        array[7] = 9;
        array[8] = 10;
        array[9] = 11;
        array[10] = 12;
        array[11] = 13;
        array[12] = 14;

    }

    public int getRandom(int[] array) {
        int cardNumber = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
        return array[cardNumber];
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print out only return value of a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858833/how-to-print-out-only-return-value-of-a-method)

Comment: Worth noting that main is a static method and you have declared getRandom(int[]) as an instance method. You'll either need to create a CardDeck instance or, more appropriately, declare the getRandom as static.

Comment: @LuisTeijon The title is similar, but that question is not similar enough to be a duplicate.

Comment: If you do not need the number for anything other than the printout, you could change the signature of the method to `public void printRandom(int[] array)` and replace `return array[cardNumber];` with `System.out.println(array[cardNumber]);`.

Comment: @Gendarme For code reusability, it's probably best to keep the method simple, and use the return value.

Comment: @4castle Is my method more complex?

Comment: Your code should use a loop to create the array. `for(int i=0;i<13;i++)array[i]=i+2;`

Comment: @Gendarme It's not more complex, it just makes it harder to reuse. In the real world, code never uses `System.out` except to debug. The code should be reusable regardless of the display medium.

Answer (score 2):

Just Print directly the return value

```
System.out.println(getRandom(array));
```

OR

```
int returnValue = getRandom(array);
System.out.println(returnValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer (Alupotha already gave you that), but you should make it a priority to learn about looping constructs.  Instead of this:

```
    array[0] = 2;
    array[1] = 3;
    ...
    array[12] = 14;
```

You could have used a `for` loop:

```
    for (int i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++) {
        array[i] = i+2;
    }
```

Comment: Yes that loop looks way more efficient!  Also, thanks everyone for taking the time to answer my super-basic noob question.